# Lock CustomRecord Serials Table

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We have a Fulfillment script in 1.0 that pulls a Serial number from the custom record based on SKU and other parameters. There is a seach that is created based on SKU and the fist available record is used. One of the criteria for search is that thee is no end user associated with the key.

We are working on converting the script to 2.0. What I am unable to figure out is, if the script(say the above functionality is put into Map function for a MR script) will run on multiple queues/instances, does that mean that there is a potential chance that 2 instance might hit the same entry of the Custom record? What is a workaround to ensure that X instances of Map function dont end us using the same SN/Key? The way this could happen in 2.0 would be that 2 instance of Map make a search request on Custom record at same time and get the same results since the first Map has not completed processing and marked the key as used(updating the end user information on key).

Is there a better way to accomplish this in 2.0 or do I need to go about creating another custom record that script would have to read to be able to pull key off of. Also is there a wait I can implement if the table is locked?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do here would be to break your assignment process into two parts or restructure it so you end up with a Scheduled script that you give an explicit queue. That way your access to Serial Numbers will be serialized and no extra work would need to be done by you. If you need hint on processing large batches with SS2 see https://github.com/BKnights/KotN-Netsuite-2 for a utility script that you can require for large batch processing.

If that's not possible then what I have done is the following:
Create another custom record called "Lock Table". It must have at least an id and a text field. Create one record and note its internal id. If you leave it with a name column then give it a name that reflects its purpose.

When you want to pull a serial number you:
read from Lock Table  with a lookup field function. If it's not 0 then do a wait*. 
If it's 0 then generate a random integer from 0 to MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

try to write that to the "Lock Table" with a submit field function. Then read that back right away. If it contains your random number then you have the lock. If it doesn't then wait*.

If you have the lock then go ahead and assign the serial number. Release the lock by writing back a 0.

- wait:
  this is tough in NS. Since I am not expecting the s/n assignment to take much time I've sometimes initiated a wait as simply looping through what I hope is a cpu intensive task that has no governance cost until some time has elapsed.